# React.js - React Router content not changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up my react.js environment to build a UI Toolkit. I'm using react-router, but for some reason the URL changes when I click on the links rendered from Index.js, but the content stays the same. It just continues displaying the content from the index.js page instead of changing to the content of the link I clicked. I'm not getting any error messages on the console.

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

function run(){
const reactMount = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history=    {browserHistory} routes={routes}/>, reactMount );
}

new Promise((resolve) => {
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve);
} else {
  window.attachEvent('onload', resolve);
}
}).then(run)
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router';

import Index from './pages/Index';
import Text from './pages/Text';
import Icon from './pages/Icon';

var routes = (
  <Route  path="/" component={Index}>
      <Route path="/Text" component={Text} />
      <Route path="/Icon" component={Icon} />
  </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

pages/Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class Index extends React.Component {
render() {

return (
  <div>
  <ul role="nav">
      <li><Link to="/Text">Text</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/Icon">Icon</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
)
}
}

export default Index;
```

pages/Text.js

```
import React from 'react';

class Text extends React.Component {
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>Text</h1>
  </div>
)
}
}

export default Text;
```

Comment: Try changing `path="/Text"` to `path="Text"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things here:

- The nested routes Text and Icon in your route configuration shouldn't have `/` before them. It should be like this: `<Route path="Text" component={Text} />`.
- In your container component (Index) you need to access `this.props.children` so that the component knows to render it's children (the nested routes).

  ```
  // Index.js

  return (
    <div>
      <ul role="nav">
        <li><Link to="/Text">Text</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/Icon">Icon</Link></li>
      </ul>

      { this.props.children }
    </div>
  )
  ```

Comment: Thank you! that fixed my issues. I totally forgot to add this.props.children. Whoops. Thanks again!